# How to loop through a list of dictionaries and write the values as individual columns in a CSV

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a list of dictionaries

d = [{'value':'foo_1', 'word_list':['blah1', 'blah2']}, ...., {'value': 'foo_n', 'word_list':['meh1', 'meh2']}]

I want to write this to a CSV file with all the 'value' keys in one column, and then each individual word from the "value"'s word_list as its own column.  So I have the first row as

foo_1 blah_1 blah_2

and so on.

I don't know how many dictionaries I have, or how many words I have in "word_list".

How would I go about doing this in Python 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to flatten each row into a normal list before writing it to the file. Something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in data:
        out_row = [row['value']]
        for word in row['word_list']:
            out_row.append(word)
        csv.writerow(out_row)
    # Shorter alternative to the two loops:
    # csv.writerow((row['value'], *row['word_list']) for row in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, but it's kind of messy (wow, I can't write a bit of code without it being in the "proper format"...how annoying):

```
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
      f.write("%s,"%(key))
    for word in d[key]:
      f.write("%s,"%(word))
    f.write("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the dictionaries one at a time, construct the list and then use the csv module to write the data as I have shown here

```
import csv

d = [{'value':'foo_1', 'word_list':['blah1', 'blah2']}, {'value': 'foo_n', 'word_list':['meh1', 'meh2']}]

with open('test_file.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for val_dict in d:
        csv_row = [val_dict['value']] + val_dict['word_list']
        writer.writerow(csv_row)
```

It should work for word lists of arbitrary length and as many dictionaries as you want.